# Warning:The Jack toolchain is deprecated Android studio

Tags: java, android, java-8, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I updated my android studio to version 3.0, I was using `jackOption` in previous version of studio. After update this warning comes. I got this warning. But i don't know where to add these two lines suggested?

```
Warning:The Jack toolchain is deprecated and will not run. To enable support for Java 8 language features built into the plugin, remove 'jackOptions { ... }' from your build.gradle file, and add

    android.compileOptions.sourceCompatibility 1.8
    android.compileOptions.targetCompatibility 1.8

Future versions of the plugin will not support usage of 'jackOptions' in build.gradle.
To learn more, go to https://d.android.com/r/tools/java-8-support-message.html
```

Comment: @pavneet 
Warning says to add these two lines. I dont need to add these too?

android.compileOptions.sourceCompatibility 1.8
    android.compileOptions.targetCompatibility 1.8

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Steps 1: Open your `build.gradle` (module app)

Steps 2: Add below lines under `android` block like

```
android {
    //.. other code
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Step 3 : synch project or click `sync now`(appear on right top corner)

Note : if you have `jackOptions` in `build.gradle`(module)

```
defaultConfig {
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}
```

then **remove jackOptions Block**

---

You can also do it via select

`File -> Project structure`

Select `app->Properties` and choose java 8 as compatibility as

[image]